# Will doing this particular merge delete the common commits instead of re-applying them?

Tags: git, merge

I've been reading an article over here: https://medium.com/anitab-org-open-source/how-i-managed-to-not-mess-up-my-git-history-thanks-to-git-pull-rebase-fed452c661f0

Based on my understanding she's got the following structure (excuse me for the rough sketch):

[image: git example commits]

She states the following problem:

> What if X approved task 2 and merged it first then review task1 and
> merged it after? Remember that task 1 has no additional codes that
> task 2 has since it was the preceding task. To make more sense, think
> of it with task 2 as the Register functionality and task 1 as the
> basic setup. Basic setup branch won’t have the Register files since I
> didn’t write that functionality on task 1. If this task 1 branch is to
> be merged after task 2, wouldn’t it cancell out (delete) the register
> folder/file that got merged by task 2 from the first merge? How can we
> prevent this?

This is the sentence that boggles my mind:

> "If this task 1 branch is to be merged after task 2, wouldn’t it
> cancell out (delete) the register folder/file that got merged by task
> 2 from the first merge?"

AFAIK, if `task2` is merged to master, it'll take that entire path that connects it uptil `master` and merges all that to `master`.

`task1` would only have 2 commits that aren't merged with master (consider those slashes to be commit ids). If we merge `task1` afterward, it shouldn't have any problems whatsoever.

Or, if `task#1` didn't have any extra commits then merging `task#1` wouldn't lead to any problems, isn't it?

It's not like commits will be "canceled out" or "deleted" if we merge `task1`. Correct?

Comment: Running `git merge` never *deletes* **any** commit. Depending on options supplied *to* `git merge` and the commit graph, the result of doing a `git merge` can be any of: no change (no merge required or possible); a new non-merge commit ("squash"); a new merge commit, with two or more parents; or no new commit but the current branch name updated (a "fast forward").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's address your questions individually.

> AFAIK, if `task2` is merged to `master`, it'll take that entire path that connects it until `master` and merge all that to `master`.

Correct. The resulting history would look like this:

```
o---o--------------M (master)
    \             /
     o---o---o---o (task2)
              \
               o---o (task1)
```

> `task1` would only have 2 commits that aren't merged with `master`. If we merge `task1` afterwards, it shouldn't have any problems whatsoever.

Also correct. There might be some merge conflicts depending on what changed in `task1`, but nothing out of the ordinary. The resulting history would look like this:

```
o---o--------------M---N (master)
    \             /   /
     o---o---o---o   / (task2)
              \     /
               o---o (task1)
```

> Or, if `task1` didn't have any extra commits then merging `task1` wouldn't lead to any problems, wouldn't it?

Nope. Git would literally tell you `Already up-to-date.` and call it quits.

> It's not like commits will be "canceled out" or "deleted" if we merge `task1`. Correct?

You're correct, commits are never deleted by a merge. Files, however, might. It depends on whether they were actively removed from the index by one of the commits that are being merged.

See, the fundamental problem with the statement you quoted from the article is this:

> If this `task1` branch is to be merged after `task2`, wouldn’t it cancel out (delete) the register folder/file that got merged by `task2` from the first merge? How can we prevent this?

When you do a merge, Git combines the trees associated with the commits you're merging compared to their first common ancestor (known as the [merge base](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base)). If a file that existed in the common ancestor was deleted in one of the commits on one side of the merge, then yes, that file would be deleted in the resulting merge.

To go back to our example:

```
o---o--------------M-----N (master)
    \             /     /
     o---o---o---o     / (task2)
         ^    \       /         
      foo.txt  o---o (task1)
                   ^
            deletes foo.txt
```

If `foo.txt` existed in the common parent between `task2` and `task1`, and `task1` deleted it, then `foo.txt` would be removed in the merge commit `N`. It's worth noting that if `task2` modified `foo.txt` after `task1`'s fork point, then you would get a merge conflict.

Now, if `task2` *created* `foo.txt`, merging `task1` wouldn't delete it in `master` simply because `foo.txt` doesn't exist in `task1`:

```
o---o--------------M--------N (master)
    \             /        /
     o---o---o---o        / (task2)
              \  ^       /
               \ creates foo.txt
                \      /         
                 o---o (task1)
```

In this case, `foo.txt` would exist in the merge commit `N`.

If you're curious to see what the resulting tree would be like if you merged two branches, you can use the [`merge-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-tree) command. For example:

```sh
git merge-tree $(git merge-base master task2) master task2
```

This would print out the paths of the files included in the tree that results from merging `master` and `task2`.